# How to kill process of another user?

Tags: c#, windows, process, kill

I want to create one small application for the kill particulate exe in all user login .

I have a server in this we are create one local domain and i create more then 100 users and that all are login with domain user like. `(domain)\userid  : xyz\josep`

Now my point is that I want to kill eg.paint.exe  from all users task manager.

How to possible in c# I don't  know how to start work.

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("paint");//?? How get process from another user?
proc.Kill();
```

Hellp sir , 
My que is not a duplicate. sorry for that I am not proper explain question. I want to kill particular exe to all employee's machine. so how can do this. this kill process method used fro own machine but i want to kill user's machine exe

Comment: It is likely that the only reason the code in your question didn't work is that you didn't remember to run it as an administrator.

Comment: Hellp sir , My que is not a duplicate. sorry for that I am not proper explain question. i want to kill particular exe to all employee's machine. so how can do this. this kill process method used fro own machine but i want to kill user's machine exe.

Comment: This is very difficult to do, but there's an existing tool, `pskill.exe`, which can be downloaded from Microsoft's web site.

Comment: Thanks to suggested @Harry , but our client require so need help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's an outline of how to do this:

- You need a [service application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that does the actual work, i.e., kills all processes running the target executable on the local machine.  Once this is done the service should stop.  If it fails, the service should stop with an error code.
- From your application, copy the service application to the target machine.
- Install the service using [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions.  Note that the [OpenSCManager function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows you to specify a remote machine.
- Launch the service using [StartService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions.  Note that StartService allows you to pass arguments to the service, e.g., the name of the executable to target.
- You can use [QueryServiceStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to poll until the service has stopped, and to retrieve the error code.  Or you could use some suitable choice of IPC between your application and the service.
- Once the job on the target machine is done, you can uninstall the service with [DeleteService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then delete the copy of the service application on the target machine.

Some notes:

- There are presumably .NET methods that you can use in place of the Win32 API functions if you prefer.  I know you can write a service application in .NET, though I've never done so myself.
- For bonus points the service application and the main application can be contained within the same executable, or the service application executable can be stored as a resource inside the main application executable.  I'm not sure whether that's plausible in .NET though.
- Obviously, the user running the main application must be an administrator on the target machine, and the target machine firewall must be configured to allow connections.  (I'm not sure offhand exactly which exceptions need to be enabled on the firewall, but at a minimum the file sharing exception.)
- This all assumes that you can't install the service on the target machine ahead of time.  If you can, that makes things somewhat simpler.  It also means the user running the main application doesn't necessarily need to be an administrator, and gives you the option of listening on a TCP/IP port of your choosing and only creating a firewall exception for that particular port.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [Process.Kill()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx), something like:

```
try
{
      Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("paint");
      proc.Kill();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); 
}
```